# Resharper search & replace pattern ignores placeholders

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, resharper

I am refactoring VB.NET code and I am trying to use following resharper replace pattern:

Search:

```
If(HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject($resourceSet$, $resourceId$), $defaultText$).ToString
```

Placeholders:

- $resourceSet$ - "exactly one argument"
- $resourceId$ - "exactly one argument"
- $defaultText$ - "exactly one argument"

(I have also tried "expression" and some others with no luck)

Replace:

```
BLGlobalRes.T($resourceSet$, $resourceId$, $defaultText$)
```

Resharper finds this pattern correclty, but replaces it with

```
BLGlobalRes.T(, , )
```

ignoring all placeholders.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a resharper issue?

Comment: @ClasG, yes, it is vb.net special syntax. "If" can be called with 2 parameters, returning first one, if it is not Nothing, and second one otherwise.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator

Comment: @ClasG, yes, I didn't include `strResul = If...` to the pattern.
About "If", the description you mentioned is corresponding to a 3-argument call. The link also contains a description for a 2-argument call, which is used in this code. Anyway, the code is working correctly, and I am just trying to replace all these calls with another function call, using Resharper VS extension to automate the process

Comment: OK, thanks for educating the ignorant ;) Now, back to "stupid" questions... The tag *regex* - that isn't really relevant, is it? And - could you provide an example of an input you'd expect to be replaced, but fails?

Comment: @ClasG, yes, _regex_ isn't really relevant (but close enough).
Example:
`If(HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("resourceSet", "resourceId"), "defaultText").ToString`
is expected to be replaced with
`BLGlobalRes.T("resourceSet", "resourceId", "defaultText")`
but it is actually replaced with
`BLGlobalRes.T(, , )`
I am 80% sure it's a Resharper bug...